# The glide install command returns [ERROR] $GOPATH is not set

Tags: go, installation, glide-golang

Im trying to install https://github.com/btcsuite/btcd

I followed the instructions (with the exception of adding sudo) by first installing glide like so

`sudo go get -u github.com/Masterminds/glide`

Then I cloned the repo to the appropriate folder like so

`git clone https://github.com/btcsuite/btcd $GOPATH/src/github.com/btcsuite/btcd`

Now the repo is located at this folder: `/Users/yako/go/src/github.com/btcsuite/btcd`

The problem occurs when I run `sudo glide install` in the folder. I get `[ERROR]    $GOPATH is not set.`

Im pretty sure I did set these correctly thought as the `go env GOROOT GOPATH` command returns

`/usr/local/go
/Users/yako/go`

and `echo $GOROOT` returns `/usr/local/go` and `echo $GOPATH` returns `/Users/yako/go`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably failing when you run it as sudo, because sudo has a different environment than your user. So a) you need to set GOPATH for that command, and b) you shouldn't need sudo for glide's installation or using it as long as $GOPATH is readable, writeable and executable by you. I don't know why btcd says to use it

Comment: weird for some reason the owner on the `GOPATH` folder was set to root instead of my user...

Comment: Odd. Maybe you used a tool to set it up running under sudo?

Comment: I change it to readable/writable/exectuble by I still get this error when running glide install `Could not create vendor: mkdir vendor: permission denied`

Comment: Im not sure if this matter but here are the permissions on my GOROOT folder `drwxr-xr-x   20 root  wheel    680 Feb 16 10:01 go`

Comment: can you run `mkdir vendor` in the directory where you are running `glide install`?

Comment: ok I didnt use the -R option when I ran `chown yako go` to change the owner so it didn't change the owners of the folders inside. we good now thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `sudo` part of the command. Glide will download your dependencies on ~/go/src/github.com/btcsuite/btcd/vendor, so you don't need superuser permissions for anything. Since you're running the command as `sudo` your environment variables are not set as If you're executing your command as `yako`